# printing a view page in asp net mvc2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-3.0

I'm developing an ASP.Net MVC2 project. What I need is that I want to print the view when user clicks a link.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Javascript on a link

```
<a href="javascript:window.print();">Print</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In combination with the answer from @M.Shuwaiee you can also take advantage of creating a style sheet specifically for the printer so your view can render more accurately for a paper layout.

http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml has some information on this.